# Why is `this` typed as `any` inside a function?

Tags: typescript

If I have a function in a module,  `TypeScript` allows me to do something like `this.unexistingFunction();` (where `unexistingFunction` doesn't exist). This happens because `this` has the type `anỳ` inside a function.

Why is that? In this context, there is no reason for `this` to be typed as any, and it is very error prone. For example if I accidentally type `this.myFunction();` instead of just `myFunction();` to call a local function, the compiler will let me do it, even though `this.myFunction();` clearly doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can enable `--noImplicitThis true` option to restrict `this` with `any` type (`this:any` won't allowed)

Example:

```
class Rectangle {
    //private w: number; //uncomment this line
    //private h: number; //uncomment this line

    constructor(w, h) {
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
    }
    getAreaFunction() {
        return () =>  {
            return this.w * this.h;
        };
    }
}
let rectangle = new Rectangle(2, 5);
let areaFunction = rectangle.getAreaFunction();
let area = areaFunction();
console.log(area);
```

**Note: compile with**  `tsc --noImplicitThis`

[Check this from Typescript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Rectangle%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fprivate%20w%3A%20number%3B%20%2F%2Funcomment%20this%20line%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fprivate%20h%3A%20number%3B%20%2F%2Funcomment%20this%20line%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(w%2C%20h)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.w%20%3D%20w%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.h%20%3D%20h%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getAreaFunction()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20()%20%3D%3E%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.w%20*%20this.h%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alet%20rectangle%20%3D%20new%20Rectangle(2%2C%205)%3B%0D%0Alet%20areaFunction%20%3D%20rectangle.getAreaFunction()%3B%0D%0Alet%20area%20%3D%20areaFunction()%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(area)%3B)

Answer (score 0):

This probably happens because you didn't `bind` your function.
In JS as well as in TypeScript, the value of `this` is determined by the invoker, rather than the declarer.
Meaning, if you pass a callback between object like so:

```js
const a = {
  a: function() {console.log(this)}
}

const b = {
  b: a.a
}

b.b(); // `this` inside the function will be the instance of `b`, not `a` where it was declared.
```

The causes the TypeScript compiler to not be able to know where the function will be invoked in compile-time, therefore it is unable to offer type information. 
To fix this, you should either `bind` the function:

```js
class a {
  constructor() {
    a = a.bind(this);
  }

  /* rest of class */
}
```

Or use arrow function:

```js
class a {
  const a = () => {};
}
```

which automatically bind to the right context.